# Posting form with input fields and multiple files selected using jQuery AJAX in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

I am attempting to manually POST a form in ASP.NET Core using jQuery AJAX as soon as the user finishes selecting multiple files. The Uploader I am using has an "selected" event where I would like to POST the form to the server using jQueryAJAX.

This exact same form posts perfectly to the server when adding a submit button to the form and clicking it on the UI. The Files are bound and the ProductId is bound. However, I am trying to avoid the page flicker. As an alternative solution I am submitting the form by calling: $("#form").submit(); in the onSelect function rather than the AJAX request.

Model looks like the following:

```
public int ProductId { get; set; }
public IList<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
```

Form looks like the following:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <ejs-uploader id="Files" showFileList="false" autoUpload="false" multiple="true" selected="onSelected" success="onSuccess" allowedExtensions=".doc, .docx, .pdf, .jpg, .jpeg, .png"></ejs-uploader>
     <input asp-for="ProductId" type="hidden" />
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript that I have been trying which is not working:

```
    function onSelected(args) {
        var files = args.filesData;
        var formData = new FormData();

        for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("files[]", files[i]);
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: false,
            url: '?handler=FileUpload',
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            headers: {
                RequestVerificationToken:
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {

            },
        });

        //$("#form").submit();
    }
```

I am using razer pages so the action method is:

```
[BindProperty]
public int MessageId { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public IList<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }

public async Task<ActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
}
```

I have also tried creating a view model: FileUploadViewModel with the same 2 properties in it.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OnPostAsync(FileUploadViewModel vm)
{
}
```

Comment: Please show your Action method

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I uploaded some additional info about the Action method. I am using razor pages which works slightly different than MVC. The page itself has the properties on it so the View Model can be eliminated. However, I was trying by also have a ViewModel as a param as well. Nothing is binding. This post is the closest thing I found to what I am trying to do, but he only does it for a single file. Additionally, I can't even get this working. https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/upload-files

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure about Razor Pages, but in MVC that would be wrong. You'd need a `[FromForm] FileUploadViewModel vm`, that might be the default though

Comment: Thinking a little more about it, you should be using `formData.append("Files", files[i]);`

Answer (score 1):

I maybe a little late to the party, however I was having the exact same issue were I wanted to manually post my request using ajax along with whatever form values the user had entered as well as any selected files for upload.
Because I was calling the controller manually with ajax the files were not being included.
Here is my ajax post request.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/home/createorder',
        data: new FormData(document.forms[0]),
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
               console.log(data);
               window.location.replace(data.redirectUrl);
        },
        error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert(data.responseJSON.error);
        },
 })
```

Here is my Model's property.

```
public IReadOnlyCollection<IFormFile> AttachmentCollection { get; set; }
```

And Finally here is my cshtml page makeup

```
 <div class="card card-5">
        <div class="card-heading">
            <h2 class="title">Attachments</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input asp-for="AttachmentCollection" class="form-control custom-file-input" multiple>
                    <label class="custom-file-label">Choose File...</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Note: Make sure you include this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>`

Answer (score -1):

According to [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), I think you have to use

```
formData.append("files[]", files[i]);
```

Instead of

```
formData.append("files", files[i]);
```

To append multiple files...

Comment: I tried this and still end up with a list of 0 files. Any idea if there is anything else wrong with my ajax request? I am not even sure if processData and contentType should both be false. I saw this in another post.

Comment: Are you kidding? The documentation says `and being compatible with PHP's naming conventions`. Where do you see PHP here?

Comment: `As with regular form data, you can append multiple values with the same name.` and in parentheses they points to PHP to... change your glasses man

Comment: It's only a variable name, is that so hard to understand? This is like saying that changing `int myName = "asd";` for `int someInt = "asd"` will suddenly make it work, those `[]` are useless there

Answer (score -1):

you can receive the attached file as a separate controller parameter of type IEnumerable` note that in order for the mapping to be done correctly you have to choose the right naming for the html input file controls , for example if your controller will have the following signature

```
public ActionResult SaveProduct(Product newproduct , IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
```

then the html input controls must be named :

```
<input type='file' name='files[0]'/>
<input type='file' name='files[1]'/>
<input type='file' name='files[2]'/>
```

and so on

don't know if there is an option to bind controls directly to the model without creating custom model binder but i have always used this option , fairly simple and easy

Comment: I need multiple files uploaded from a single file input.

Comment: HttpPostedFIleBase is **not** ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET Core uses IFormFile

Comment: then you can create one input control and map it to one action parameter of type 
<input type='file' name='files' multiple />
IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> or as blake suggested IFormFile